# How to save a value to a file after a person has entered the value in terminal in C?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I am pretty much beginner to C and creating a user login system. For that I have made an multi-dimensional array and when a person will register its name, his/her username gets appended to the array but it does not save changes to that array. So, when I re-run that program again and enter that same username i had used for registration, that username is not accepted.

What I basically want is that when I register any username, the program appends that username to the array in which all usernames are stored as well as saves that username in the array so that it can get recognised afterwards.

So, is there any solution for this?

Comment: Never mind learning C, but it's a bit of a language from the stone age, likely older than your parents. You'll find yourself re-inventing the wheel over and over again. (Or, like Basile suggests, pull in third party libraries.) If you have a choice, learn C++, C#, Java, or a script language like Python. They all come with a lot of help for handling strings, files, mapping of one data item which is not an integer to another etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A practical approach to your problem is to use some database library, like [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/). Or some indexed file library like [GNU gdbm](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/gdbm.html) or T[okyo Cabinet](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tokyocabinet/).

You certainly will need some [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) specific API to manage time. For Linux, see [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). For Windows, study the [Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/).

If you want to manage millions of users you could use some relational database server, e.g. [PostGreSQL](https://postgresq.org/). Then read some [SQL tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/).

You could decide to keep the user related data in [JSON](https://json.org/) format.

Read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and look into [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website. See also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), use it as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

Both [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) and [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) could be inspirational.

PS. Don't ignore legal issues, e.g. [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/) in Europe.

Comment: well I was thinking about this only btw ty

Comment: Given that the user is a beginner, I don't think that they are programming a real life application, let alone for millions of users. Most likely, a simple linear file will be totally fine, with neither names nor passwords allowing whitespace. This is just the very first attempt to keep state between program runs.